# Optimize query getting the Primary Key

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to optimize my query? When I add this parameter, my stored procedure add 6 seconds to output my result.

```
SET @primary_name  =    
            ISNULL(
                STUFF((SELECT 
                        'Convert(nvarchar(4000),' + column_name + ')+'',,''+'
                        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
                        WHERE 
                            OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(constraint_name), 'IsPrimaryKey') = 1
                            AND QUOTENAME(table_schema) + '.' + QUOTENAME(table_name) = @table_name 
                        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
                ,1,0,'')
            ,'ISNULL')

SET @primary_name = (LEFT(@primary_name,LEN(@primary_name) -6 ))

IF @primary_name = ''
BEGIN
SET @primary_name = ''''''
END
```

Comment: No problem. Just wanted to help you get answers.:D

Answer (score 0):

Can you try removing the ISNULL and do it in the second SET operation?

Answer (score 0):

Just got the Code from the execution reduce by 6 seconds @TavoloPerUno

```
SELECT @primary_name  = (SELECT top 1 QUOTENAME(keys.COLUMN_NAME) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE keys
                            WHERE keys.TABLE_NAME =PARSENAME(@table_name, 1)
                              and keys.TABLE_SCHEMA = PARSENAME(@table_name, 2)
                            and OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(constraint_name), 'IsPrimaryKey') = 1)
```